# How to include a hardcoded field value with params.permit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def employee_params
 params.permit(:first_name, :phone)
end
```

```
def create
 employee = current_admin.organization.admins.new(employee_params , code: "91")
 employee.save 
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
```

So how can I add the hardcoded value for the field code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
employee = current_admin.organization.admins.new(employee_params.merge(code: "91"))
```

But its better to have this logic in model, something like following

```
before_create :add_code

def add_code
  self.code = '91'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be added as default value in db level

```
change_column :employee, :code, :string, :default => "91"
```

Or

You could make use of callbacks in your case before_create or before_save

```
# app/models/employee.rb

class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :set_defaults


  def set_defaults
    self.code ||= '91'
  end
end
```